# Entity framework core postgres enum type does not exist

Tags: entity-framework-core, npgsql

I have a column in postgres of type enum (name of the enum/type in the database : `document_validity`).

Entity framework generates the following (part of the) code when I query the column:

```
...
SELECT CASE
WHEN d3."Validity" IN ('not_checked'::document_validity, 'rejected'::document_validity) THEN 4
ELSE 1
...
```

This throws an exception saying

```
Npgsql.PostgresException (0x80004005): 42704: type "document_validity" does not exist
```

I'm able to make the query manually work by adding the name of the schema before the name of the enum type (name of the schema : "Main"):

```
SELECT CASE
WHEN d3."Validity" IN ('not_checked'::"Main".document_validity, 'rejected'::"Main".document_validity) THEN 4
ELSE 1
```

How can I tell entity framework to prefix the enum type with the schema name ?

I'm doing code first (if that's important). Here is the model:

```
public enum DocumentValidity
{
    NotChecked = 0,
    Validated = 1,
    Rejected = 2,
}

public class Document
{
    ...
    public DocumentValidity Validity { get; set; }
    ...
}

public class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    ...
    static MyDbContext()
        => NpgsqlConnection.GlobalTypeMapper.MapEnum<DocumentValidity>();

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
        => builder.HasPostgresEnum<DocumentValidity>();
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. Since my schema is not the default `public` schema, I had to add it to the `MapEnum` call.

```
static MyDbContext() => NpgsqlConnection.GlobalTypeMapper.MapEnum<DocumentValidity>("Main.document_validity");
```